# How do I get multiple matrices within a loop and assign them automatically?

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a list containing 15 different groups that I want to convert into 15 different matrices in a for loop. However, I could not make it work.

```
a=split(datalist,as.factor(datalist$groups))
```

When I do this I can visualize different groups by typing a[1] a[2] etc. my each a component (a[1], a[2] etc) were in a list and have size of 3x24 and they were considered as non-numeric. I get these components after using split command. but I need them as numeric that is why I thought I need to convert them into matrices and for that, I try to make a loop which converts those components into 15 different matrices which are 3x24 in size.

for each i number (from 1 to 15) I can get a matrix by using

```
matrix(unlist(a[i]), ncol=columnlength,byrow=rowlength)
```

this command.

Then I start my loop

```
    for (i in 1:15) {
  b[i]=matrix(unlist(a[i]), ncol=24,byrow=3)

    }
```

It is wrong since I am using b[i] which specifies only one unit of a matrix. But I do not know what to use instead of b[i].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach I show using `mtcars`

First, split like you're already doing

```
split.df <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

Then, create new variables labeled `a` thru `letters[N]`

```
newnames <- letters[1:length(split.df)]
```

Use `assign` to `<-` the variable name and data

```
for (x in 1:length(newnames)) {
      assign(newnames[x], as.matrix(split.df[[x]]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your problm.

```
a=split(datalist,as.factor(datalist$groups))
```

the "a" result is an vector or matrix|data.frame?

then you crate "b" matrix, 3x24

you want put every "a" element into "b" matrix, right?

your "a" have 24 elements with 3 element each? (like a matrix...)

```
b <- as.matrix(a)
```

cannot resolve your problem?